# transposed xml transaction data display as html table in xslt2

Tags: xml, xslt

got following xml data, which at a very simple level "simulates" some bank account transactions (withdraws only):

```
<trnsctns>
 <trnsctn date="19/01/01">
  <OB>100</OB>
  <amnt/>   
 </trnsctn> 
 <trnsctn date="19/03/03">  
  <OB/>
  <amnt>33</amnt>
 </trnsctn>
 <trnsctn date="19/02/02">
  <OB/>
  <amnt>22</amnt>
 </trnsctn>
 <trnsctn date="19/05/05">
  <OB/>
  <amnt>7</amnt>
 </trnsctn>
 <trnsctn date="19/04/04">
  <OB/>
  <amnt>32</amnt> 
 </trnsctn>
</trnsctns>
```

where amnt is the amount withdrawn through the current month from that initial OB=100 (opening balance);
if no amount withdrawn, then the initial balance remains unchanged (like in the first month - where no amount present so the 19/02/02 transaction date OB's value is still 100, and so forth) and the CB (closing balance) - which is a calculated field - has a very simple formula = OB - amnt, with one note though: current CB (calculated field)
became the next OB ..
The way the result displayed is like this:

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
 <tr><th>crrntNmbr</th><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><th>OB</th><td>100</td><td>100</td><td>78</td><td>45</td><td>13</td></tr> 
  <tr><th>amnt</th><td>-</td><td>22</td><td>33</td><td>32</td><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><th>CB</th><td>100</td><td>78</td><td>45</td><td>13</td><td>6</td></tr>
 <tr><th>date</th><td>19/01/01</td><td>19/02/02</td><td>19/03/03</td><td>19/04/01</td><td>19/05/05</td></tr>
</table>
```

[image: p3]

Also the fields should be ascending ordered by date (which is in "yy/mm/dd" format - I'd also like to know how to ascending order this dates if they would be formated as "dd/mm/yy");
one could easily notice it's not the same order from the xml data file ...

And the aproximate xslt transformation is as follows (has a lot of errors ... which need to be fixed )

```
<xsl:template match="/">
 <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
  <tr><th>crrntNmbr</th>
     <xsl:for-each select="trnsctns/trnsctn">
      <td><xsl:number/></td>
     </xsl:for-each>
   </tr>
  <!-- rows for OB, amount, CB, and date -->
   <xsl:for-each select="trnsctns/trnsctn[1]/*">
     <xsl:variable name="fldNme" select="name()"/> 
      <tr><th><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></th>
       <xsl:for-each select="//trnsctn/*[name()=$fldNme]"> 
         <xsl:variable name="OB" select="trnsctn[position()]/OB"/>
         <xsl:variable name="amt" select="trnsctn[position()]/amnt"/>
         <xsl:variable name="CB" select="$OB - $amt"/> <!-- error ! -->
           <td><xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="name() = 'OB'">
                 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="name() = 'amnt'">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                 </xsl:when>
                 <xsl:when test="name() = 'date'">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                 </xsl:when>
                 <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="$CB"/>  <!-- not good also .. -->
                 </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </td>
           </xsl:for-each>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </xsl:template>
```

xslt 2, please help me with this .. Slightly updated
thanks in advance ..

Comment: It seems the first step should be to sort the transactions by date. However, I am not sure how to do even that, since the format of the date is not clear.

Comment: I guess the date format is yy/mm/dd -- a pretty weird choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are too many issues here for a single question.

Try this as your starting point; it shows how you can sort the transactions (assuming the format is DD/MM/YY), then process them sequentially and also handle an empty `amnt`:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/trnsctns">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>date</th>
            <th>ob</th>
            <th>amnt</th>
            <th>cb</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:call-template name="process">
            <xsl:with-param name="transactions" as="element()*">
                <xsl:perform-sort select="trnsctn">
                    <xsl:sort select="replace(@date, '(.{2})/(.{2})/(.{2})', '$3$2$1')"/>
                </xsl:perform-sort> 
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="process">
    <xsl:param name="transactions"/>
    <xsl:param name="tx" select="$transactions[1]" />
    <xsl:param name="ob" select="$tx/OB" />
    <xsl:variable name="amnt" select="$tx/amnt" />
    <xsl:variable name="amnt" select="if ($amnt/text()) then number($amnt) else 0" />
    <xsl:variable name="cb" select="$ob - $amnt" />
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tx/@date"/>
        </td>   
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$ob"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$amnt"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$cb"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:if test="count($transactions) > 1">
        <xsl:call-template name="process">
            <xsl:with-param name="transactions" select="$transactions[position() > 1]"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="ob" select="$cb"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result (rendered):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to understand your requirements fully enough to give a proper answer, but let me help you to remove some of the faults in your XSLT code.

```
   <xsl:for-each select="//trnsctn/*[name()=$fldNme]"> 
     <xsl:variable name="OB" select="trnsctn[position()]/OB"/>
```

The `for-each` selects an element that is a child of a `trnsctn` element, and the xsl:variable selects a child of that child whose name is `trsnsctn`. That isn't going to match anything in the data you have shown us.

When the expression in a filter `A[B]` is an integer, it means `A[position()=B]`. So if you write `A[position()]`, it means `A[position()=position()]` which is always true.

```
<td><xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="name() = 'OB'">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:when>
```

An `xsl:choose` that branches on the name of the element means you're going out of your way to avoid using the key feature that gives XSLT its power, namely template rules.

Comment: Thank very much mr. Kay for your valuable insight over this ...
The point here is that I wanted to display all those node exactly as mr. Hor pointed in the answer, but exactly with rows and columns transposed: rows becomes columns and columns become rows; need this as want to display all ths over some mobile screen where ain't got enough room to properly present all the stuff needed.
 @michael.hor257k Thanks very much, very interesting solution. Really good .. But, please, can you make it - as already mentioned - with rows and columns transposed? 
  Thank you again all of you !!!

Comment: @mirexS As I said, there are too many issues here at once, and my answer already deals with more than one (which it shouldn't). If you really need to transpose the table (why?) put it in a variable first, then process it in another step. Here's an example you could use for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67680625/3016153. Ask a separate question, if necessary.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - ok, thanks again. I'll try doing all these as you suggested.

Comment: I am still not sure why you should bother. As a user, I would expect each transaction to be a row - just like in bank statement.

Comment: @michael - yes you're perfectly right! But as I mentioned .. there are a lot of stuff which still I need to display over a mobile phone ..
 Over a mobile! That's why ... And actually the stuff is much more complex than this, as I posted here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77642207/three-records-at-once-xml-mobile-pagination-on-xslt-p-iii-last?noredirect=1&lq=1
 but .. perhaps of the question's complexity didn't get any answer whatsoever ..
 So , please .. if you could help me with all those transpose, I'd thank you million of times ..
  I'm in really need to do this ..
    thanks

Comment: @michael.hor257k Do you think you can still help me with this transposed xml data display .. place rows in place of columns and vice-versa ?
  Please you gents help me through this .. Really got stuck with this , as there are a couple of other stuff to do ..
 Just updated the question a little bit ..
 Didn't want to make a new post as already done at least two or something and not getting an answer !
  Please you guys help me with all this
   Thanks very much in advance ..

Comment: I gave you my answer already.