# xml transposed transaction sorted data display as html table in xslt2

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

got the following xml simple account transactions data (as already stated over some previous post):

```
<trnsctns>
 <trnsctn date="01/01/19">
  <OB>100</OB>
  <amnt/>   
 </trnsctn> 
 <trnsctn date="03/03/19">  
  <OB/>
  <amnt>33</amnt>
 </trnsctn>
 <trnsctn date="02/02/19">
  <OB/>
  <amnt>22</amnt>
 </trnsctn>
 <trnsctn date="05/05/19">
  <OB/>
  <amnt>7</amnt>
 </trnsctn>
 <trnsctn date="04/04/19">
  <OB/>
  <amnt>32</amnt> 
 </trnsctn>
</trnsctns>
```

and through a xslt2 transformation similar to this one (taken from previous michael hor's answer):

```
<xsl:template match="trnsctns">
    <table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
      <tr><th>crrntNmbr</th>
        <xsl:for-each select="trnsctn">
         <th><xsl:number/></th>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>    
     <xsl:call-template name="process"> 
       <xsl:with-param name="transactions" as="element()*">
         <xsl:perform-sort select="trnsctn">
          <xsl:sort select="replace(@date,'(.{2})/(.{2})/(.{2})','$3$2$1')"/>
         </xsl:perform-sort>
       </xsl:with-param>
     </xsl:call-template>
     <tr>
      <th>date</th>
       <xsl:for-each select="trnsctn">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@date"/></td>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>     
  </table>
 </xsl:template>
   
 <xsl:template name="process"> <xsl:param name="transactions"/> <xsl:param name="currentIndex" select="1"/>
 <tr>
   <th><xsl:value-of select="name($transactions[1]/*[position() = $currentIndex])"/></th>
    <xsl:for-each select="$transactions">
     <xsl:variable name="currentTransaction" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="$currentTransaction/*[position() = $currentIndex]"/>      
     <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="if ($currentValue/text()) then $currentValue else '-'"/>
     </td>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </tr>
  <xsl:if test="$currentIndex &lt; count($transactions[1]/*)">
   <xsl:call-template name="process">
     <xsl:with-param name="transactions" select="$transactions"/>
     <xsl:with-param name="currentIndex" select="$currentIndex + 1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

I need to display that above xml data structure like this:

```
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
 <tr><th>crrntNmbr</th><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td></tr>
  <tr><th>OB</th><td>100</td><td>100</td><td>78</td><td>45</td><td>13</td></tr> 
  <tr><th>amnt</th><td>-</td><td>22</td><td>33</td><td>32</td><td>7</td></tr>
  <tr><th>CB</th><td>100</td><td>78</td><td>45</td><td>13</td><td>6</td></tr>
 <tr><th>date</th><td>19/01/01</td><td>19/02/02</td><td>19/03/03</td><td>19/04/01</td><td>19/05/05</td></tr>
</table>
```

which will be rendered like this:

[image: p_1]

Still, through the xslt showcased above the rendering goes like this:

[image: p_2]

So one could easily notice there is one important line missing (and dates not sorted at all):

[image: l_4]

Now, as already stated ([transposed xml transaction data display as html table in xslt2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77662990/transposed-xml-transaction-data-display-as-html-table-in-xslt2)), the logic of some calculated fields goes as follows (apologise for keep repeating ..)

- transposed rows with columns and CB from current record/node is the next OB of the next record or node

But one very important thing, dates(in the following format: "dd/mm/yy") have to be ascending orderly sorted. Then,

- first column is the header column
- second column is actually the first data row
  initial OB = 100 (actual xml data value)
  amnt = nothing or " - "
  CB = 100 - 0 = 100
- third column (second data row)
  OB = previous line CB = 100
  amnt = 22
  CB = OB - amnt = 100 - 22 = 78
  data =  as it is (but properly sorted as stated above)
- fourth column (third data row)
  OB = previous line CB = 78
  amnt = 33
  CB = OB - amnt = 78 - 33 = 45
  data =  as it is (properly sorted as stated above)
  and so forth.

This would be it.
Very sorry for keep asking same question over and over again, but I'm in a great need for this to
make it work.
Please, you guys, help me with this
Thank you all for support and understanding

Comment: Does the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77662990/transposed-xml-transaction-data-display-as-html-table-in-xslt2/77663359#77663359 give you the correct values in the right order, only the table formats (rows instead of columns) is not what you want the output to look like? Which XSLT processor do you use, some of the computations of values based on previous ones seems to be suited for XSLT 3 accumulators (and all supported version of e.g. Saxon Java, Saxon .NET, SaxonJS, SaxonC) do support XSLT 3 anyway.

Comment: Yes, it does, only if one needs to display the regular html table as records like regular rows with ordinary columns. That M. Hor's solution works really great, apprecuate it. But as stated couple of times now, I need all those xml nodes to be transposed .. 
 And in fact this "almost" xslt transform showcased up here was actually based over that M. Hor's answer you just mentioned.
 Can't use for moment saxon, as I'll need this for a mobile where is difficult to work with saxon ..
 So please mr Honnen (or mr. Hor, or ..) help me with this xslt2 solution. 
  Thank you all in advance ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is XSLT 3 code that builds on the answer posted in [transposed xml transaction data display as html table in xslt2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77662990/transposed-xml-transaction-data-display-as-html-table-in-xslt2/77663359#77663359) and adds a function to convert the result table there from rows to column format (and to add a `crrntNmbr` row); I have not tried to move the `date` column which was first in the original result to be the last row, instead it is the second row after the `crrntNmbr` row:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
<xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:swap-table" as="element(tr)*">
  <xsl:param name="rows" as="element(tr)*"/>
  <xsl:for-each select="1 to count($rows[1]!*)">
    <xsl:variable name="col" select="."/>
    <tr>
      <th>{$rows[1]/*[current()]}</th>
      <xsl:for-each select="2 to count($rows/*[1])">
        <td>{$rows[current()]!*[$col]}</td>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="/trnsctns">
    <xsl:variable name="data-table">
      <tr>
          <th>date</th>
          <th>ob</th>
          <th>amnt</th>
          <th>cb</th>
      </tr>
        <xsl:call-template name="process">
            <xsl:with-param name="transactions" as="element()*" select="trnsctn => sort((), function($t) { replace($t/@date, '([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})', '$3$2$1')})"/>
        </xsl:call-template>          
    </xsl:variable>
      
    <table border="1">
      <xsl:sequence select="$data-table"/>
    </table>
    
    <xsl:variable name="swapped-table" select="mf:swap-table($data-table/tr)"/>

    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>crrntNmbr</th>
        <xsl:for-each select="1 to count($swapped-table[1]/*) - 1">
          <td>{position()}</td>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tr>
      <xsl:sequence select="$swapped-table"/>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="process">
    <xsl:param name="transactions"/>
    <xsl:param name="tx" select="$transactions[1]" />
    <xsl:param name="ob" select="$tx/OB" />
    <xsl:variable name="amnt" select="$tx/amnt" />
    <xsl:variable name="amnt" select="if ($amnt/text()) then number($amnt) else 0" />
    <xsl:variable name="cb" select="$ob - $amnt" />
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tx/@date"/>
        </td>   
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$ob"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$amnt"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$cb"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:if test="count($transactions) > 1">
        <xsl:call-template name="process">
            <xsl:with-param name="transactions" select="$transactions[position() > 1]"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="ob" select="$cb"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online fiddle using SaxonJS 2.6](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Amf%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fmf%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20method%3D%22html%22%20version%3D%225.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Afunction%20name%3D%22mf%3Aswap-table%22%20as%3D%22element%28tr%29*%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22rows%22%20as%3D%22element%28tr%29*%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each%20select%3D%221%20to%20count%28%24rows%5B1%5D%21*%29%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22col%22%20select%3D%22.%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3E%7B%24rows%5B1%5D%2F*%5Bcurrent%28%29%5D%7D%3C%2Fth%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each%20select%3D%222%20to%20count%28%24rows%2F*%5B1%5D%29%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%7B%24rows%5Bcurrent%28%29%5D%21*%5B%24col%5D%7D%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Afunction%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2Ftrnsctns%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22data-table%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3Edate%3C%2Fth%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3Eob%3C%2Fth%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3Eamnt%3C%2Fth%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3Ecb%3C%2Fth%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acall-template%20name%3D%22process%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Awith-param%20name%3D%22transactions%22%20as%3D%22element%28%29*%22%20select%3D%22trnsctn%20%3D%3E%20sort%28%28%29%2C%20function%28%24t%29%20%7B%20replace%28%24t%2F%40date%2C%20%27%28%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%29%2F%28%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%29%2F%28%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%29%27%2C%20%27%243%242%241%27%29%7D%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acall-template%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Avariable%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22swapped-table%22%20select%3D%22mf%3Aswap-table%28%24data-table%2Ftr%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctable%20border%3D%221%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cth%3EcrrntNmbr%3C%2Fth%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Afor-each%20select%3D%221%20to%20count%28%24swapped-table%5B1%5D%2F*%29%20-%201%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%7Bposition%28%29%7D%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Afor-each%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Asequence%20select%3D%22%24swapped-table%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftable%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20name%3D%22process%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22transactions%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22tx%22%20select%3D%22%24transactions%5B1%5D%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22ob%22%20select%3D%22%24tx%2FOB%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22amnt%22%20select%3D%22%24tx%2Famnt%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22amnt%22%20select%3D%22if%20%28%24amnt%2Ftext%28%29%29%20then%20number%28%24amnt%29%20else%200%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22cb%22%20select%3D%22%24ob%20-%20%24amnt%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ctr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22%24tx%2F%40date%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22%24ob%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22%24amnt%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Ctd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avalue-of%20select%3D%22%24cb%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftd%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Ftr%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aif%20test%3D%22count%28%24transactions%29%20%3E%201%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acall-template%20name%3D%22process%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Awith-param%20name%3D%22transactions%22%20select%3D%22%24transactions%5Bposition%28%29%20%3E%201%5D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Awith-param%20name%3D%22ob%22%20select%3D%22%24cb%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acall-template%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aif%3E%20%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E&input=%3Ctrnsctns%3E%0D%0A%20%3Ctrnsctn%20date%3D%2219%2F01%2F01%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3COB%3E100%3C%2FOB%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Camnt%2F%3E%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%3C%2Ftrnsctn%3E%20%0D%0A%20%3Ctrnsctn%20date%3D%2219%2F03%2F03%22%3E%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3COB%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Camnt%3E33%3C%2Famnt%3E%0D%0A%20%3C%2Ftrnsctn%3E%0D%0A%20%3Ctrnsctn%20date%3D%2219%2F02%2F02%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3COB%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Camnt%3E22%3C%2Famnt%3E%0D%0A%20%3C%2Ftrnsctn%3E%0D%0A%20%3Ctrnsctn%20date%3D%2219%2F05%2F05%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3COB%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Camnt%3E7%3C%2Famnt%3E%0D%0A%20%3C%2Ftrnsctn%3E%0D%0A%20%3Ctrnsctn%20date%3D%2219%2F04%2F04%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3COB%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Camnt%3E32%3C%2Famnt%3E%20%0D%0A%20%3C%2Ftrnsctn%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Ftrnsctns%3E&input-type=XML).

[image: Screenshot of that fiddle on Android phone].

Comment: ok, mr. Honnen, thank you very much .. 
 So, I really have to rely over the saxon, as this is xslt3 .. right?

Comment: Well, last time I asked you said you use Saxon and all supported versions of Saxon, whether that is SaxonJS 2.6 or Saxon 11 or 12 for Saxon Java or SaxonC or SaxonCS or 10 for Saxon.NET do support XSLT 3. But there is not a lot of XSLT 3 specific stuff in there but text value templates you could rewrite with `xsl:value-of` (and revert the use of `fn:sort` to `xsl:perform-sort`).

Comment: Oh, yes ... you're right .. I think is out of scope on telling here how and why I'm using Saxon or other versions. Point is you're absolutely right, and I thank you very much on this solution; been struggling with months now and you literally save a lot of time of wondering, checking and everything. Thank you again very much !